# Django query assigns database columns to wrong model instance properties

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Really weird problem - when I query for a model instance the data comes back assigned to the wrong properties.

The model:

```
class SaleLineItem(models.Model):
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sale_line_items")
    stock_unit = models.ForeignKey(StockUnit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sale_line_items")

    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    price_original = models.FloatField()
    price_paid = models.FloatField()

    tax_amount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    num_sold = models.IntegerField()

    sale_line_item_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SALE_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

The database row:

```
  id   | currency | price_original | price_paid | tax_amount | num_sold | sale_line_item_id |  status   | sale_id | stock_unit_id 
-------+----------+----------------+------------+------------+----------+-------------------+-----------+---------+---------------
 15726 | THB      |            130 |        130 |            |        1 |                   | delivered |   16219 |             2
```

And the query:

```
sli = SaleLineItem.objects.get(pk=15726)
print(sli.pk)
-------------------------
16219

print(sli.stock_unit_id)
-------------------------
THB

print(sli.currency)
-------------------------
130.0
```

The data get populated on the object but everything is "shifted" by one column.

But if I do the query this way:

```
SaleLineItem.objects.filter(pk=15726).values()
-------------------------
<QuerySet [{'id': 15726, 'sale_id': 16219, 'stock_unit_id': 2, 'currency': 'THB', 'price_original': 130.0, 'price_paid': 130.0, 'tax_amount': None, 'num_sold': 1, 'sale_line_item_id': None, 'status': 'delivered'}]>
```

. . . the result is correct.

I thought I might have un-migrated models but I ran both makemigrations and migrate to no effect.

Same result when I use lower-level QuerySet methods:

```
qs = SaleLineItem.objects.all()
clone = qs._chain()
clone.query.add_q(Q(pk=15726))
print(clone)
------------------------------
<QuerySet [<SaleLineItem: SaleLineItem object (16219)>]>
```

Note the pk on the model `__str`__ is incorrect.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Running:

Python 3.7.3
Django 2.2.1
Postgres 10

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's because I overrode __init__ with an extra (non-field) argument.

```
    @classmethod
    def from_db(cls, db, field_names, values):
        if len(values) != len(cls._meta.concrete_fields):
            values_iter = iter(values)
            values = [
                next(values_iter) if f.attname in field_names else DEFERRED
                for f in cls._meta.concrete_fields
            ]
        new = cls(*values)
        new._state.adding = False
        new._state.db = db
        return new
```

Database values are populated onto the model using *values, and the model expects fields in a specific order. So you can't have an extra argument in __init__ or the order gets messed up.

Edit:

Had not read this part in the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/):

> You may be tempted to customize the model by overriding the __init__
>   method. If you do so, however, take care not to change the calling
>   signature . . .